# encoding utf-8 on linux

Tags: linux, encoding

I have a file CreateTable.sql. When I do :

```
file --mime-encoding CreateTable.sql
```

The result is :

```
CreateTable.sql: utf-8
```

The command :

```
lot of things ...
UNICODE, UNICODEBIG, UNICODELITTLE, US-ASCII, US, UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16,
UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32, UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE, UTF7, UTF8, UTF16, UTF16BE,
UTF16LE, UTF32, UTF32BE, UTF32LE, VISCII, WCHAR_T, WIN-SAMI-2, WINBALTRIM,
lot of things
```

But the command more on the file CreateTable.sql print :

```
CREATE TYPE enum_branchement_moderattachement AS ENUM(
   $$Inconnu$$,
   $$Relatif par rapport Ã  l'amont Ã©lectrique$$,
   $$N'a jamais Ã©tÃ© rattachÃ©$$,
   $$GÃ©ographique$$,
   $$DÃ©tachÃ©$$,
   $$SimplifiÃ©$$
);
```

What I did wrong ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: I used a script to create table on postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with those lines :

```
echo $LANG
```

that give me fr_FR

```
export LANG=fr_FR.utf8
```

Hope that can help someone else.